# How to draw a line on image using matlab where the end points are not able to specify?

Tags: line, matlab-figure

I have used line() function in matlab to draw line over an image. The line is drawn successfully but the problem is it is not saving on the image or in other words I can't save the line drawn image. I need this lined image for later stages. I can see the lined image. But it is not shown when again that particular image is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too specific, but to give you an idea. Images in Matlab are saved as a matrix so you have a column and row of values.

You can alter or access a column or a row of an image easily using the `:` operator. For instance, to get the first row of data you can do `img(1,:)`, that is to mean all elements in the first row.

I hope with this hint you can solve your problem easily.

Comment: Thanks. My actual problem is not finding the co-ordinates, but saving the lines.

Comment: after plotting the lines, you have to save the matlibplot figure. That can be done using [pyplot.savefig](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig).
So first show your image, display the lines, then  save the figure window.
Alternatively you can do that by changing values of pixels in the image by determining through which image indices the line pass.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for

```
hold on;
```

For example:

```
figure();
plot(1:10,1:10);
hold on;
plot(1:10,2:11,'r')
```

Comment: Thanks #Andrey I used hold on; but still it doesn't shows any differences. Actually I have extracted some vertical edges from an image . Now I need to draw lines connecting these edges. For this I used line() function.  Later I need to count the number of lines drawn. This is my need.